# daab 5 update oracle NCLOB column

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

is there another way to fix this?
i just find this works

```
DbCommand comm = db.GetStoredProcCommand(usp_Script_Update);
        db.AddInParameter(comm, "v_ID", DbType.String, WindowsGuid2OracleGuid(script.ID));
        db.AddInParameter(comm, "v_Name", DbType.String, script.Name);
        db.AddInParameter(comm, "v_Description", DbType.String, script.Description);

        ((OracleDatabase)db).AddParameter((OracleCommand)comm, "v_ScriptValue", OracleType.NClob, script.ScriptValue.Length,
            ParameterDirection.Input, true, 0, 0, "ScriptValue", DataRowVersion.Default, script.ScriptValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DbType.StringFixedLength`